# CSS: 0px margin not working

Tags: html, css

I've set the `margin` for a particular div to `0px` on all sides, but when I inspect it in Chrome it still shows a margin. I have no idea why this is happening:

[image]

As you can see there is `margin: 0px` in the CSS and Chrome indicates in the lower right that the element has no margin. However, when I hover over the div there is a large orange region to the right indicating the margin.

Here is my HTML:

```
        <div id="content">
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="black_mirror.html">Black Mirror</a></li>
                    <li><a href="hoc.html">House of Cards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="inception.html">Inception</a></li>
                    <li><a href="interstellar.html">Interstellar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="st.html">Stranger Things</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="home-page-images">
                <img src="images/black_mirror_cover.jpg" class="home-page-image home-page-image-left" />
                <img src="images/hoc_cover.jpg" class="home-page-image home-page-image-right" />
                <div class="clear-float" />
                <img src="images/inception_cover.jpg" class="home-page-image home-page-image-left" />
                <img src="images/interstellar_cover.jpg" class="home-page-image home-page-image-center" />
                <img src="images/st_cover.jpg" class="home-page-image home-page-image-right" />
            </div>

            <div class="clear-float" />
        </div>
```

Here is some of my CSS:

```
div.clear-float {
    clear: both;
}

div.home-page-images {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 600px;
}

div#container {
    /* TODO: Vertically center */
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    color: white;    
    width: 960px;
}

div#nav {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

div#nav a:hover, div#nav a:active {
    /* color: #FDF9BD; */
}

div#nav a:link, div#nav a:visited {
    /*
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    */
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div#nav li {
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

div#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: I think `margin: 0` not `0px` (I'm not sure about it)

Comment: Please edit your question to have a working code snipet which re-procduced your problem

Comment: @shashanth both woks when its 0

Comment: @SureshKaria I didn't know it. Thanks! :)

Comment: From the question it's not clear what you expected to happen. Instead of showing blank space to the right of the div, what was the browser supposed to do?

Comment: @MrLister - I've seen this question in various forms recently, so I suspect it must have been a change in Chrome's behaviour. The point is that it shows the used right margin in orange - the colour for margins. The expectation is that the browser would show the computed margins in orange, not the used margins, so that space would be transparent rather than orange.

Answer (score 2):

DIVs are block level elements: they'll "take up" all of the horizontal space provided to them by the parent. That means, even if you manually set the width of a div to something less than the width of the parent, *it'll still take up all of the horizontal space*. If you add a `display: inline-block` to the div, your "margin" will disappear.

Of course, that may affect the rest of your layout, but that's another problem entirely.

Answer (score 0):

> Margin is 0 on each sides!

The empty space is not margin.Its just a space displaying because you have given fixed 600px width to block element.

You are looking **[box-model](https://hackernoon.com/til-using-box-model-of-chrome-dev-tools-c1cdd4081693)** layout displaying "-" means its 0 or not set. You have fixed width of element try making it 100% width or removing width it wont show space right side.

Or check in **[computed tab](http://docs.joomlabamboo.com/getting-started/how-to-use-the-computed-panel-in-the-chrome-inspector)** you will see all the property of margins there.

Comment: It *is* a margin, but you won't see the margin in the computed tab because it's not a margin in the computed values, it's a margin in the used values. See [the difference between specified, computed and used values here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html#value-stages)